# VSTS task - .NET Core Publish - build error

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, docker-compose, azure-devops

I defined a VSTS task:
[image]

and I'm getting an error:

2017-11-09T21:25:07.8842340Z ##[section]Starting: Publish copy
2017-11-09T21:25:07.8969280Z ==============================================================================
2017-11-09T21:25:07.9036290Z Task         : .NET Core
2017-11-09T21:25:07.9066480Z Description  : Build, test, package, or publish a dotnet application, or run a custom dotnet command. For package commands, supports NuGet.org and authenticated feeds like Package Management and MyGet.
2017-11-09T21:25:07.9092700Z Version      : 2.1.8
2017-11-09T21:25:07.9122030Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2017-11-09T21:25:07.9153020Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=832194)
2017-11-09T21:25:07.9181040Z ==============================================================================
2017-11-09T21:25:10.3802130Z [command]/opt/vsts/work/_tool/dncs/2.0.0/x64/dotnet publish /opt/vsts/work/1/s/Api/Api.csproj --configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output .\obj\Docker\publish
2017-11-09T21:25:13.3290490Z Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.3.409.57025 for .NET Core
2017-11-09T21:25:13.3323650Z Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
2017-11-09T21:25:13.3347770Z 
2017-11-09T21:25:20.3979410Z   Core -> /opt/vsts/work/1/s/Core/bin/$(BuildConfiguration)/netcoreapp2.0/Core.dll
2017-11-09T21:25:25.7586100Z   Infrastructure -> /opt/vsts/work/1/s/Infrastructure/bin/$(BuildConfiguration)/netcoreapp2.0/Infrastructure.dll
2017-11-09T21:25:29.5066330Z   Api -> /opt/vsts/work/1/s/Api/bin/$(BuildConfiguration)/netcoreapp2.0/Api.dll
2017-11-09T21:25:29.6098500Z   /bin/sh: 2: /opt/vsts/work/_temp/tmpbae052718c06412094faac10781aa78e.exec.cmd: BuildConfiguration: not found
2017-11-09T21:25:29.6143540Z   /bin/sh: 2: /opt/vsts/work/_temp/tmpbae052718c06412094faac10781aa78e.exec.cmd: BuildConfiguration: not found
2017-11-09T21:25:29.6211710Z   /bin/sh: 2: /opt/vsts/work/_temp/tmpbae052718c06412094faac10781aa78e.exec.cmd: BuildConfiguration: not found
2017-11-09T21:25:29.6241270Z   The specified deps.json [/opt/vsts/work/1/s/Api/bin//netcoreapp2.0/Api.deps.json] does not exist
2017-11-09T21:25:29.6291470Z /opt/vsts/work/_tool/dncs/2.0.0/x64/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razor.viewcompilation/2.0.0/build/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.ViewCompilation.targets(60,5): error MSB3073: The command ""/opt/vsts/work/_tool/dncs/2.0.0/x64/dotnet" exec --runtimeconfig "/opt/vsts/work/1/s/Api/bin/$(BuildConfiguration)/netcoreapp2.0/Api.runtimeconfig.json" --depsfile "/opt/vsts/work/1/s/Api/bin/$(BuildConfiguration)/netcoreapp2.0/Api.deps.json" "/opt/vsts/work/_tool/dncs/2.0.0/x64/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razor.viewcompilation/2.0.0/build/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.ViewCompilation.dll" @"obj/$(BuildConfiguration)/netcoreapp2.0/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razor.viewcompilation.rsp"" exited with code 129. [/opt/vsts/work/1/s/Api/Api.csproj]
**2017-11-09T21:25:29.8180470Z ##[error]Error: /opt/vsts/work/_tool/dncs/2.0.0/x64/dotnet failed with return code: 1**
2017-11-09T21:25:29.8479220Z [command]/opt/vsts/work/_tool/dncs/2.0.0/x64/dotnet publish /opt/vsts/work/1/s/Core/Core.csproj --configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output .\obj\Docker\publish
2017-11-09T21:25:32.4096960Z Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.3.409.57025 for .NET Core
2017-11-09T21:25:32.4130000Z Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
2017-11-09T21:25:32.4144900Z 
2017-11-09T21:25:36.5861200Z   Core -> /opt/vsts/work/1/s/Core/bin/$(BuildConfiguration)/netcoreapp2.0/Core.dll
2017-11-09T21:25:37.0659300Z   Core -> /opt/vsts/work/1/s/Core/obj/Docker/publish/
2017-11-09T21:25:37.2400410Z [command]/opt/vsts/work/_tool/dncs/2.0.0/x64/dotnet publish /opt/vsts/work/1/s/Infrastructure/Infrastructure.csproj --configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output .\obj\Docker\publish
2017-11-09T21:25:41.0598300Z Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.3.409.57025 for .NET Core
2017-11-09T21:25:41.0623670Z Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
2017-11-09T21:25:41.0638670Z 
2017-11-09T21:25:44.2113060Z   Core -> /opt/vsts/work/1/s/Core/bin/$(BuildConfiguration)/netcoreapp2.0/Core.dll
2017-11-09T21:25:46.3659950Z   Infrastructure -> /opt/vsts/work/1/s/Infrastructure/bin/$(BuildConfiguration)/netcoreapp2.0/Infrastructure.dll
2017-11-09T21:25:46.8807460Z   Infrastructure -> /opt/vsts/work/1/s/Infrastructure/obj/Docker/publish/
2017-11-09T21:25:47.0068230Z [command]/opt/vsts/work/_tool/dncs/2.0.0/x64/dotnet publish /opt/vsts/work/1/s/UnitTests/UnitTests.csproj --configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output .\obj\Docker\publish
2017-11-09T21:25:53.3168330Z Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.3.409.57025 for .NET Core
2017-11-09T21:25:53.3196560Z Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
2017-11-09T21:25:53.3212230Z 
2017-11-09T21:26:06.3861780Z   Core -> /opt/vsts/work/1/s/Core/bin/$(BuildConfiguration)/netcoreapp2.0/Core.dll
2017-11-09T21:26:08.8367810Z   Infrastructure -> /opt/vsts/work/1/s/Infrastructure/bin/$(BuildConfiguration)/netcoreapp2.0/Infrastructure.dll
2017-11-09T21:26:14.1992030Z   Api -> /opt/vsts/work/1/s/Api/bin/$(BuildConfiguration)/netcoreapp2.0/Api.dll
2017-11-09T21:26:20.5782420Z   UnitTests -> /opt/vsts/work/1/s/UnitTests/bin/$(BuildConfiguration)/netcoreapp2.0/UnitTests.dll
2017-11-09T21:26:21.4168980Z   UnitTests -> /opt/vsts/work/1/s/UnitTests/obj/Docker/publish/
**2017-11-09T21:26:21.5707390Z ##[error]Dotnet command failed with non-zero exit code on the following projects : /opt/vsts/work/1/s/Api/Api.csproj
2017-11-09T21:26:21.5945250Z ##[section]Finishing: Publish copy**

Do you havy any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue mainly caused by **the variable `$(BuildConfiguration)` which you didn't defined in your VSTS build definition**.

So you can add the variable `BuildConfiguration` with the value as `release` or `debug` in Variables Tab of the build definition, then queue the build again.

[image]